How to load the excel data in grid without using OLEDB driver?
Our application is going to deploy in Azure Environment as a PAAS. Hence we can not install any driver. Therefore looking for any substitute which can able to load dataset in grid without using OLEDB Driver. My Application is .NET 4.8 framework based.
Existing Code
///
/// Return dataset representing attached excel file
///
/// 
/// 
public DataSet FillDataSet(DataSet ds,int rows_to_ignore)
{
  int max_empty_allowed = 2;
  if (ds == null)
    ds = new DataSet();
  DataSet _tmpds = new DataSet();      
  this._dc = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(this.Connection);      
  this._dcomm = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
  this._dcomm.Connection = this._dc;
  this._dcomm.CommandText = this.CommandText;
  this._adapter = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(this._dcomm);
  try
  {
    this._adapter.Fill(ds);
    if (ds.Tables.Count == 0)
      return ds;
    if (rows_to_ignore > 0)
    {
      while(rows_to_ignore > 0)
      {
        ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].Delete();
        rows_to_ignore--;
      }
      ds.Tables[0].AcceptChanges();
    }
    _tmpds = ds.Clone();
    ///Ignore empty rows
    int empty_row = 0;
    foreach(DataRow _dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
      int emptyCount = 0;
      foreach(DataColumn _dc in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
      {
        if (_dr[_dc] == DBNull.Value)
          emptyCount++;            
      }
      if (emptyCount != ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count)
        _tmpds.Tables[0].ImportRow(_dr);
      else
      {
        empty_row++;
        /// Reached empty allowed count ignore rest of excel sheet
        if (empty_row >= max_empty_allowed)
          break;
      }
    }        
    this._dc.Dispose();
    return _tmpds;[text]
  }
  catch(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException oex)
  {
    throw oex;
  }
}


Looking for any substitute which can work in PAAS
